# How should I index my columns in my MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a simple SQL table designed as such:

```
id, username, platform, time
```

The Id and Username are strings, Platform and Time are ints.

I'm getting slow queries with 1 million rows, especially when I'm ordering the top rows by time played. How could I improve all my use cases in one pass?

I need to:

- paginate, ordered by descending time played
- get the row number of a id / username / platform combo
- update the time played on a id / username / platform combo

Thank you for you help.

Edit:

Here are the queries.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 `rank`, `id`
FROM leaderboard, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r ORDER BY `time` DESC)
AS `ranks` WHERE `id`=:id;

SELECT * 
FROM leaderboard 
ORDER BY `time` DESC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET :page;

REPLACE INTO leaderboard
(`platform`, `id`, `username`, `time`)
VALUES (:platform, :id, :username, :time);
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the query or queries that you want to optimize.

Comment: I just did it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Those "combo" are too vague; please provide the `SELECT`.

Comment: The slow request is the first SELECT. Sorry if I worded my question poorly, I could not remember on the top of my head if I checked the platform and id or only the id. It's the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To order by descending time, you want an index on `t(time)`.  This assumes that there are no `where` clauses or `group by` clauses in the query.

To access by `id`/`username`/`platform` combos, you want an index on `(id, username, platform)`.  This assumes that the comparisons are all equality and connect by a `and`.